# How to get daily usage of Youtube API qouta?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube data API and I didn't find anything related to the overall daily usage of API limit.
I can check the same on the console and I visited the below link but here I can only calculate the stats from the youtube web portal.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Is there any means that I can get the overall daily usage of from any API provided by youtube.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had this requirement too. But then I moved on as it was not a blocker for me.
Alternatively I would suggest keeping track of quota units consumed. You can easily calculate how many quota units are consumed from the chart in the link you provided. You can get the number of quota units left by subtracting the sum of units consumed from 10000 (Current default limit, or any number assigned to your account if you requested for more).

The quota gets reset every midnight PST.

FYI, the api does respond with an HTTP 403 and error code 403 with reason = dailyLimitExceeded. Once you encounter this then you can stop sending out more api calls till midnight.

If you ever get to know of an API endpoint please update this question so that it helps people like us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Go to [here](https://console.cloud.google.com), click on the menu in the top left corner, IAM & Admin and then Quotas.